# Setter Injection in WCF Unity

Tags: wcf, unity-container

For using Unity in WCF Service can i use Setter Injection? or do we need to follow the steps as mentioend in the below blog.

http://geekswithblogs.net/13DaysaWeek/archive/2010/12/01/dependency-injection-and-wcf-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use the steps mentioned in the link you provided (IMO it's the best used way) **and** the setter injection. Once you have set up your system in the way described there (ServiceBehavior, ServiceHost and ServiceHostFactory), you can use the setter injection in your service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService {

   private MyOtherObject myDependency;

   // here MyOtherObject will be injected
   [Dependency()]
   public MyOtherObject {
     set { myDependency = value; }
   }

   void MyServiceMethod(string stuff) {  
       // TODO
   }

}
```